# I want to embed text and stickers to video

Tags: android, ffmpeg, mediametadataretriever

Is there any easy approach to embed text and sticker to video. 
`I don't want to use overlay`

I want to embed(**add it to video permanently**). Can i do this without using  FFmpeg (NDK library). Is there any way using MediaMetadataRetriever.